# Subset on multiple genes in Seurat

Tags: r, rna-seq, single-cell, seurat

I know that I can do subsetting on just one gene in `Seurat`:

```
seurat_subset <- SubsetData(seurat_object, subset.name = neuron_ids[1], accept.low = 0.1)
```

However, I want to subset on multiple genes. Is there a way to do that? I just do not want to do manual subsetting on 10 genes, then manually getting `@data` matrix from each subset, and recreating seurat object afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to achieve this in the following way:

```r
require(data.table)
cell_names <- vector(mode="character")
for (i in 1:length(neuron_ids)) {
  seurat_subset <- SubsetData(seurat_object, subset.name = neuron_ids[i], accept.low = 0.1)
  genes <- colnames(seurat_subset@data)
  cell_names <- c(cell_names, genes[! genes %chin% cell_names])
}
seurat_subset <- SubsetData(seurat_object, cells.use = cell_names)
```

Would be interesting to know if `Seurat` provides such functionality out of the box.

Comment: In Seurat V3 you should use `seurat_subset <- SubsetData(seurat_object, cells = cell_names)` as `cells.use` is no longer supported.